# How to skip confirmation with use-package :ensure?

Tags: use-package

I am trying to install Emacs [vterm](https://github.com/akermu/emacs-libvterm). Following its documentation, I added this to my `init.el`:

```
(use-package vterm
    :ensure t)
```

I have made sure that the dependencies are installed in my system (Ubuntu 22.04, Emacs 28). The install went well. However, it required a confirmation in the status line before I can continue:

> Vterm needs `vterm-module' to work.  Compile it now? (y or n)

This breaks automatic initialization on remote machines.

*Is there way in `use-package` (or Emacs in general) to suppress such confirmation so that Emacs will skip the question as if a `yes` or `y` is provided as the answer?*

Answer (score 1):

I know of no way to suppress *all* confirmations but in the case of `vterm` you can do:

```
(setq vterm-always-compile-module t)
```

From the docstring of that variable:

> If not nil, if ‘vterm-module’ is not found, compile it without asking.